# Where is my view in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-express

I have a table structured like this:

```
sensorId int, Value int, obDate datetime
```

in SQL Server 2008 Express.

I want to get the latest value for each sensor, so I've created a View Like this:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[LAT_POLDATA] 
AS (
    SELECT A.sensorId, A.obDate, A.Value 
    FROM [Met].[dbo].[POLDATA] AS A
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT sensorId, MAX(obDate) AS obDate 
         FROM [Met].[dbo].[POLDATA] 
         GROUP BY sensorId) AS B ON A.sensorId = B.sensorId 
                                 AND A.obDate = B.obDate 
)
```

Now If I query `Select * from [dbo].[LAT_POLDATA]` I get values when I do this in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, but I don't see this view under the `Views` in my database.

If I query it from a ASP.net Service, the query fails and throws an error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'LAT_POLDATA'

Where is the view? Why don't I see it SSMS?

Comment: Sorry if the question is to trivial, but, did you refresh your views? Management studio won't show newly created objects until you refresh...

Comment: That's the first thing I did.

Comment: And you did not create it on `Master` or any other DB by any chance? Or maybe within a transaction?

Comment: not to promote a product, but you can download this free tool from redgate that allows you to search all objects in your sql instance: http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/ 
You can search all databases on your server for the view name then

Comment: Probably you might have created the view under Master database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Management Studio please try adding your preferred database name and execute it.

```
use [yourDatabaseName]

Select * from [dbo].[LAT_POLDATA]
```

If that gives you an error that view is not in your database

Then follow this

```
USE [yourDatabasename]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

Create View [dbo].[LAT_POLDATA] AS (
    SELECT A.sensorId , A.obDate , A.Value 
    FROM [Met].[dbo].[POLDATA] AS A
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT sensorId , MAX(obDate) AS obDate 
        FROM [Met].[dbo].[POLDATA] 
        GROUP BY sensorId  
    ) AS B
        ON A.sensorId  = B.sensorId 
        AND A.obDate  = B.obDate 
)

GO
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. It's not in my database. So how do I make the View, so that it is created in my database and not in the master database? When I use `use [yourDatabaseName]` before the create view statement, I get the error message: `'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch`

Comment: Try adding `GO` between the `USE [...]` line and the `CREATE VIEW` line

Answer (score 1):

Execute this query and see if you can find it here, this query will return all the views created in you database

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name
 ,name AS view_name
 ,OBJECTPROPERTYEX(OBJECT_ID,'IsIndexed') AS IsIndexed
 ,OBJECTPROPERTYEX(OBJECT_ID,'IsIndexable') AS IsIndexable
 FROM sys.views
 WHERE name LIKE 'LAT_POLDATA%'
 GO
```